# Can I choose which region Amazon CodeWhisperer uses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, amazon-codewhisperer

I want to use Amazon CodeWhisperer in Europe - that is, when my code is sent to AWS, I don't want my data to leave Europe. Is this possible? In IntelliJ, the AWS Toolkit has a region selection box, but it doesn't look like that's applied when you are using an AWS Builder ID with CodeWhisperer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't know too much with this plugin made by AWS, you may create issues at there issue tracker: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues